# How do I make fonts look heavier than this in my output pdf file?

Tags: fonts

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Wind energy provides an indirect form of solar energy. It is a proven technology which helps in meeting the demands in electricity in an efficient way. Offshore



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: latin modern, like computer modern, is a very light font. there are literally thousands of other fonts you could use (less if you need matching math)

Comment: As David says, if you want a font that looks different, then you should use a different font. Have a look at the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

Comment: `\usepackage[mathpazo}` instead of `lmodern`

Answer (score 1):

> [image]

Sorry my code is a terrible mess, I just typed this out quickly, but here's how to do it:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\garamond}{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily{\libertine}{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily{\fancycap}{EB Garamond Initials}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{3in}
        \resizebox{3in}{!}{%
            \garamond A Few Quick Font Options:}
        \resizebox{3in}{!}{%
            \textsl{(Remember not to forget} 
            \textsc{Small Caps} \& 
            \textbf{Bold} 
            \emph{\garamond\& 
            \normalfont \textit{italics}}}
        \resizebox{3in}{!}{%
            \garamond and 
            {\garamond \small Optical Sizes \&} 
            \normalfont numbers oldstyle 
            \garamond 123456 and lining 
            \garamond \addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining}} 123456)}
        \vspace*{-14pt}\\\resizebox{3in}{!}{%
            \garamond \tiny —The above paragraph accomplished using 
            \texttt{\textbackslash usepackage\{lmodern\}} \& 
            \texttt{\textbackslash usepackage\{fontspec\}} for 
            \textsc{EB Garamond}—}\par
        \vspace*{.125\baselineskip}\ \\
        \raisebox{6ex}{\rule\linewidth{.4pt}}
        \vspace*{-4\baselineskip}\ \\\par
        \scriptsize\libertine \lettrine[lines=3,loversize=-.3,lraise=.25]
        {\fancycap F}{onts} can be included using \texttt{\textbackslash 
        usepackage\{fontname\}} as shown on \LaTeX font lists. There I 
        would recommend \texttt{libertine} as a replacement for \texttt{%
        lmodern} if you want something slightly heavier. However, \texttt{%
        \textbackslash fontspec} is where the fun really starts, so check 
        that out along with fonts like \textsc{EB Garamond} that have 
        features required for good typography. \medskip\par\ \hfill\tiny 
        This paragraph set in Linux Libertine, with EB Garamond Lettrine.
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Here is the list of fonts that can be used in plain LaTeX: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

For anything else, use `fontspec` in XeLaTeX or LuaTeX. Also note this gives you utf8 input be default, so things like em-dashes, Cyrillic, Greek, and simplified Chinese can by typed.

So... TL;DR: try swapping `\usepackage{lmodern}` for `\usepackage{libertine}` and see what you think. The best way to use EB Garamond is `\setmainfont{EB Garamond}`. Note that the `fontspec` package is required for `\newfontfamily` and `\setmainfont`.

Comment: Is using xelatex mandatory? If so, I think you should mention it explicitly. In any case: I learned a lot from your example.

Comment: @ChristianLindig Using XeLaTeX is not mandatory for any of the fonts listed here: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ but for using OTF and TTF fonts it is. `fontspec` in XeLaTeX actually has amazing OTF support, even better than Apple Pages and even Adobe InDesign. I use it a lot because it's the only free way there is to access truly top-notch typography.

Comment: @Ryan `lualatex` can also be used with OTF and TTF fonts.

Comment: @Thérèse yeah, I thought I mentioned that in my answer... LuaLaTeX is awesome in its own right.